# SignalR: sending a messages only to current server connected clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I've messages broadcasted by my workers to all my web instances using a Service Bus Topic.
Each web instances are then responsible to stream those messages to the connected users using SignalR.

My problem is that SignalR is also using Service Bus to display it's own messages to connected users application wide (which is great!). So each web instances "re forward" the messages from the workers to Service Bus creating the following issues:
1. messages are streamed X times to each connected clients (X = the number of web instances)
2. there is hundred of thousands (up to millions) messages per hour, and each message ho through Service Bus X+1 times (1 time from the worker + X times because of SignalR), leading to more (useless) Service Bus costs

=> I'm looking for a way to tell SignalR to only stream particular messages to it's own connected clients, without using the backplane. Using a Queue to send the messages from the workers to the web instances instead of a Topic partially solve the problem (messages are only streamed once to the clients, but messages still go through Service Bus twice).

Any solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing your own message bus which is non trivial but possible.

Comment: Hard solution to a very simple problem :(